# VK mini apps. Аунтефикация пользователя

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vk-mini-apps

У меня имеется приложение на Vue.

Решил разместить его во ВКонтакте, чтобы оно стало vk mini apps. По сути vk mini apps открывает "сайт приложения" во фрейме, но каким способом можно авторизовать пользователя? Ведь не передается никаких данных (проверял куки, localStorage, header заголовки), всё пусто. Если смотреть на другие приложения, то при входе в них пользователь сразу авторизирован в приложении под своими данными из VKConnect. Собственно, плавно перешли к вопросу, каким способом можно авторизовать пользователя VK в своем vk mini apps приложении?

Answer (score 1):

Если интересует авторизация на клиенте, то пользователь там уже авторизован. Вам остается лишь вызвать метод инициализации `connect.send("VKWebAppInit", {});`

Для авторизации на сервере нужно для начало проверить параметр GET: sign на то, что пользователь действительно открыл приложение вконтакте, [подробнее](https://vk.com/dev/vk_apps_launch_params). После проверки нужно получить токен пользователя по его code, тоже приходит в GET.